# Is it safe to grant all privileges to a public-facing app in a MySQL/MariaDB database?

Tags: mysql, security, mariadb

Consider this:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myapp.* TO 'myapp'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

From the [DigitalOcean documentation on how to create a new MySQL user](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql):

> Warning: Some users may want to grant their MySQL user the ALL PRIVILEGES privilege, which will provide them with broad superuser privileges akin to the root user’s privileges [...] Such broad privileges should not be granted lightly, as anyone with access to this MySQL user will have complete control over every database on the server.

I have a public-facing third-party app that requires an unknown amount of privileges, but I still want it to be safe. Assuming I can't infer what privileges are actually used, what is the broadest set of privileges I can assign to my new user without it becoming a security hazard? Is it `ALL PRIVILEGES` or something else?

For example, how does the `CREATE USER` privilege work? Assuming I have access only to database A and not B, does having `CREATE USER` allow me to create a brand new user that has access to database B, thereby bypassing the restriction imposed on myself? I'm assuming not, but I hope this makes the thought process clear.

Comment: Rethink the use of `WITH GRANT OPTION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set of privileges that is "safe" if random users are able to execute arbitrary SQL on your database server.

I could grant nothing but `USAGE` to a MySQL user (i.e. they can connect but nothing else), and if that user can execute arbitrary SQL, they can bring down the server.

So the more important question is, how can you use application code to restrict what SQL statements can be run?

And also, never allow your database instance to be directly reachable by folks on the internet. You should use network infrastructure (routing and firewalls) to make sure only clients on your application server can connect to the database.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was exactly what I meant. Nothing is directly reachable, it's the application that uses the DB. I guess I didn't ask it clearly enough.

Comment: If your application is the only client that can run SQL queries, what risk are you worried about?

Comment: That the client might get hacked.

Comment: Well, if the client is hacked, SQL privileges are the least of your worries.

Comment: I disagree. If the app is configured with the proper file system permissions etc, the attacker might remain stuck in the app and not cause harm to other critical data in the database.

Comment: "Stuck in the app"? What does that mean?

Comment: That the attacker can do anything in the app but s/he has yet to gain access to anything else.

Comment: If the attacker can do anything in the app, including run arbitrary SQL queries, then SQL privileges are not an adequate defense.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll mark your answer as accepted.